# How to edit method after sent request

Tags: java, httprequest, httpclient, executorservice, completable-future

I want to get four values from a website but need to edit parameter every step. I thought I can do it with executors but I couldn't. So, how can I edit parameter in every CompletableFuture before sending?

```
        HttpRequest httpRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .version(Version.HTTP_1_1)
            .uri(URI.create(sourceUrl))
            .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8")
            .method("POST", BodyPublishers.ofFile(Paths.get("Resources/Payload.txt")))
            .build();

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder()
            .executor(executorService)
            .connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
            .build();

        CompletableFuture<HttpResponse<String>> a = 
            httpClient.sendAsync(httpRequest, BodyHandlers.ofString());

        CompletableFuture<HttpResponse<String>> b = 
            httpClient.sendAsync(httpRequest, BodyHandlers.ofString());

        CompletableFuture<HttpResponse<String>> c = 
            httpClient.sendAsync(httpRequest, BodyHandlers.ofString());

        CompletableFuture<HttpResponse<String>> d = 
            httpClient.sendAsync(httpRequest, BodyHandlers.ofString());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `HttpRequest.Builder` and let it build two alternating instances.
Generally speaking, once you call `.build()` on it, the configuration is done.
eg. add a method which takes `string` and then returns instance of `HttpRequest`
... where the basic intention is, to reduce duplicate code.

Answer (score -1):

An `HttpRequest` is stateful, meaning one instance can't represent multiple requests.

You have to create a new instance for each request.

Comment: Can I do it with CompletableFuture? I am getting error 'Type mismatch: cannot convert from HttpRequest to CompletableFuture<HttpRequest>'

Comment: No, the `CompletableFuture` in your question will return an `HttpResponse` not a `HttpRequest`.  The idea here is the request has been made, and you are waiting for the response.  You cannot edit the request after it's sent, and looking at the javadocs, I don't think `HttpRequest` objects can be reused.

Comment: HttpRequest objects returned by the HttpRequest.Builder can be reused, but can't be modified. As suggested before, the way to optimize code reuse is to keep the builder around and use it to build multiple requests. It's only worthwhile if the requests are similar - that is - if there are a lot of parameters supplied to the builder that do not vary.

Comment: Not sure why I got downvoted.  The javadocs for `HttpRequest` make no guarantees about immutability or state and one of the implementation classes, `jdk.internal.net.http.HttpRequestImpl` sure looks mutable/stateful to me.

Comment: @Taylor The JDK implementation of HttpRequest.Builder::build returns an immutable HttpRequest. It is not an instance of HttpRequestImpl (which is an implementation private class). This could have been made clearer in the API documentation. There is no way to enforce that other implementations of HttpRequest.Builder will do the same, but the intent for the builder was always to return immutable objects.

Comment: The class level documentation of the builder states:
```
Once built an HttpRequest is immutable, and can be sent multiple times. 
```
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpRequest.Builder.html